# Add UISplitViewController via addChildViewController

Tags: objective-c, layout, rotation, uisplitviewcontroller, childviewcontroller

I have one UIViewController in which another viewcontroller(1) and splitviewcontroller(2) do switching via addchildviewcontroller method. So when I add splitviewcontroller it doesn't handle correct the rotations. Look at the video – https://dl.dropbox.com/u/2139277/IMG_0180.MOV.

Here is the code that does switching:

```
- (void)transitionFromViewController:(UIViewController *)fromViewController toViewController:(UIViewController *)toViewController
{
    if (fromViewController == toViewController)
        return;
    // animation setup
    toViewController.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
    // notify
    [fromViewController willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
    [self addChildViewController:toViewController]; 
    // select animation direction
    UIViewAnimationOptions animation = (_contentState == ContentStateViewingMap) ? UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp : UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlDown;
    // transition
    ContentState previousState = _contentState;
    _contentState = ContentStateAnimating;
    [self transitionFromViewController:fromViewController
                      toViewController:toViewController
                              duration:0.6
                               options:animation | UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                            animations:nil
                            completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                [toViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
                                [fromViewController removeFromParentViewController];
                                _contentState = (previousState == ContentStateViewingMap) ? ContentStateViewingList : ContentStateViewingMap;
                            }];
}
```

Comment: perhaps add more detail describing the issue in technical terms, and explain more specifically what your question is.

Comment: @mcknz the question is how to fix this blinking

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK a UISplitViewController MUST be the root view controller of the window. Adding it as child view controller is not supported.

Comment: But it works great when i add it to tabbarcontroller in stotyboard

Comment: Still, it is not intended to be used like that and if you insist on using it differently than Apple has designed it for then you will find all sorts of things not behaving as you might expect. Apple calls this "the behavior is undefined."